# Segmentation fault strcpy/strcat

Tags: c, strcpy, strcat

I am writing a program to open a file (say "input_file"), manipulate its contents and then output it to another file ("manipulated-input_file")

I have done this with strcpy and strcat in the following way:

```
char t-filename[]="Manipulated-", filename[50], td-filename[50];
memset ( filename, '\0', FILE_NAME);

printf("Please enter the filename - \n");
scanf( "%30s", filename );
strcpy(td-filename,filename);
strcat(t-filename,td-filename);
printf("%s\n", t-filename);
```

Now printf functions prints the t-filename as "Manipulated-input_file"

After this part, I have a section where I open "input_file" and
do something.

```
fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
while ( fgets (line, sizeof line, fptr) != NULL)
{
 ...do something...
}
fclose(fptr);
```

Later I wanted to open a file with name 't-filename' at the end of the code:

```
tptr = fopen(t-filename, "w");
fprintf(tptr,"something");
fclose(tpr);
```

When I compile this code I am getting "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

I do not know what went wrong. Can somebody help?

Comment: Can you post the real code instead of this? Given that `t-` etc are not valid identifiers in the C language and this code can never compile.

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mcve], preferably one that we can copy-paste (as is without modifications) and try ourselves.

Comment: As a hint though: Think about the size of `t-filename`. How many elements do you think that array will have?

Comment: I will post the code...

Comment: From the edit. As commented `transfilename` has no spare elements into which `strcat(transfilename,translatedfilename);` can work. It immediately overflows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`transfilename` doesn't have enough space to hold additional items added there by `strcat(transfilename,translatedfilename);`. It's already full with `"Translated-"` since `[]` gives you the exact amount of characters in the initializing string, plus a null terminator.

You need to either change it to `char transfilename [LARGE_ENOUGH]` or use dynamic memory allocation to change the size in run-time.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I set dynamic memory in this case? Does it mean that I have to use char transfilename[SIZE] after reading the 'filename'?

Answer (score 2):

`strcat(t-filename,td-filename);`

`t-filename` is not large enough to accommodate the result and it is an Undefined Behaviour.

same here

`strcat(transfilename,translatedfilename);`

`transfilename` is not large enough to accommodate the result and it is an Undefined Behaviour.